# How to convert a defined list to a set in Racket?

Tags: racket

If I have a list already defined of random strings, how can I create the same set with those same strings? Below is the code I used to make the list.

```
(define (make-random-integer)
(modulo (random 1000) 25)
)


(define (list45 n)
(build-list n (λ (x) (build-string 10 (λ (x) (integer->char (+ 65 (make-random-integer)))))))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most direct answer to your question is to use `list->set`.

The most elegant answer (in my opinion) is to use `for/set`:

```
(define (random-string-set items len)
  (for/set ((i (in-range items)))
    (build-string len (thunk* (integer->char (+ (char->integer #\a) (random 26)))))))
```